# Как сделать плавающий диапазон?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, время

Я всё хочу написать своего первого мини-бота, но столкнулся с трудностью определения диапазона. В зависимости от положения он меняется. Есть условный поплавок (2.png), который двигается по определённой шкале, которая имеет ограниченные размеры. Если за них зайти условная рыба соскользнет:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss.linux import MSS as mss
import time
import pyautogui as pg
import imutils
import mss
import numpy
import pyautogui

template = cv2.imread("2.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

color_yellow = (0, 255, 255)

mon = {'top': 80, 'left': 350, 'width': 100, 'height': 100}

global old_x  # Объявляем old_x как глобальную переменную
old_x = None  # Изначально устанавливаем old_x в None
time_sleeps = 1.5  # Изначально устанавливаем время ожидания в 1.5 секунды

def process_image(original_image):
    processed_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    processed_image = cv2.Canny(processed_image, threshold1=200, threshold2=300)
    return processed_image


def ss():
    global old_x, time_sleeps  # Объявляем как глобальные переменные
    op = 1
    button_down = False  # Флаг для отслеживания состояния кнопки мыши
    school_start_x = 200  # Начало горизонтальной школы (замените на реальные значения)
    school_end_x = 600  # Конец горизонтальной школы (замените на реальные значения)

    with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = {"top": 40, "left": 0, "width": 800, "height": 640}

        while "Screen capturing":
            last_time = time.time()
            img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))
            gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray_frame, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            loc = np.where(res >= 0.7)

            if loc[0].size > 0:  # Проверяем, есть ли элементы в массиве loc
                op += 1
                print(op)

                for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
                    cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
                    for p in img:
                        x = pt[0]
                        y = pt[1]
                        print(x)
                        if 400 <= x <= 440:  # Диапазон горизонтальной школы
                            if not button_down:
                                pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
                                button_down = True
                            time.sleep(time_sleeps)
                            print('x ===', x)
                        else:
                            if button_down:
                                pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
                                button_down = False
                            old_x = None  # Сбросим old_x, чтобы не изменять время ожидания
                            continue
            else:
                if button_down:
                    pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
                    button_down = False
                old_x = None  # Сбросим old_x, чтобы не изменять время ожидания

            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            if op > 35:
                return


def screen_record():
    sct = mss.mss()
    last_time = time.time()

    while True:
        img = sct.grab(mon)
        print('loop took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - last_time))
        last_time = time.time()

        img = np.array(img)
        processed_image = process_image(img)
        mean = np.mean(processed_image)
        print('mean = ', mean)

        if mean <= float(0.11):
            print('SSSSSSSS ')
            pyautogui.click(button='left')
            break
            return
        else:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            continue

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.moveTo(431, 175, duration=1)
    pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
    pyautogui.moveTo(470, 200, duration=1)
    pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
    time.sleep(2)
    screen_record()
    time.sleep(0.01)
ss()
```